# Open-source font similar to Bourgeois Medium (with characteristic N letter)

Tags: font-recommendation

I'm new here, so I'll start with saying hello! :)

I'm looking for open-source alternative to Bourgeois Medium. I need it to have that characteristic N, like you can see below:

[image: Bourgeois Medium Font]

I appreciate all help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That N is pretty unique. I can't find anything quite like it.

You could find an existing SIL Open Font at fontlibrary(dot)org, modify the N glyph, change the name, and allow others to use it with the same licence and copyright - in essence make a derivative font with a new unique name.  You can get font editing software such as Fontforge, which is free.